# PayPal IPN messages issues

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm currently using PayPal's adaptive payment system to process purchases on my e-commerce platform.

This has been working successfully for the past 5 years. Last week, there was a situation where my platform's system did not record IPN responses from PayPal. This was an intermittent issue. Lets say, 5 transactions were made in a day - 3 were recorded and 2 weren't. Note that there was no code change done in recent times. I also tried resending IPN messages from PayPal's IPN history page, but to no success.

On contacting PayPal, I was asked to check my IPN listener, which again had no issues. I'm quite puzzled as to what might be causing these issues.

In the last 24 hours, all the transactions stopped receiving IPN messages. On checking PayPal's IPN history page to retry sending IPN messages, I could not find any of the messages for the transactions that happened today. I am unable to process confirmation numbers for my customers without the IPN message from PayPal.

Any insights to this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the silver bullet answer you're looking for but I'm in a similar position as you. We've only been intermittently receiving IPN messages from Adaptive Payments for the past few days. Other IPN messages seem unaffected. Last night we received a number of IPN messages from transactions as far back as 5 days ago and as of today everything appears to be normal. I have no idea what was wrong and so I'm not ready to call it "fixed", but I'm hopeful.

The only action I've taken (besides spending the past two days manually confirming payments), was opening a ticket at paypal-support.com. I can't say for certain if that had any effect as they have yet to tell me if they've taken any action, only asked for more details.

As a side note, I can't find any service status pages for Adaptive Payments. Presumably this is because it's a limited release product, however it's slightly frustrating as we do depend on it until PayPal offers a better alternative for chained payments to multiple endpoints.

Comment: They had a big issue in malformed IPN response from July 1st to July 15-16th that has now finally been fixed, this you reported should be a newser issue but if it is intermittent and you started getting IPNs again, it may have been a temporary delivery issue. We're now facing another issue, the svcs endpoint don't respond anymore to any of our calls since 23 of July and when we land on paypal we get an "invalid trasaction" error in the page and a javascript error to the checkout.js object in the console, more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57269749/adaptive-payments-flow-is-broken